# EF6 Use multiple tables with same type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, partitioning

I have a table called "Thing" with columns ID (guid) and JunkLevel (which can be 0, 1 or 2), and 20 others. Over a million rows are added daily. About 70% are JunkLevel 0, 1% JunkLevel 1, and the rest JunkLevel 2.

We've decided to create 3 tables to contain things: Junk0Thing, Junk1Thing, Junk2Thing and remove the JunkLevel column. This is for performance, as we want to do special things with the Junk1Things, but the number of rows makes it a pain with all the other stuff.

We want Entity Framework to expose 3 DbSets (Junk0Things, Junk1Things, Junk2Things) but with only a single C# class type, "Thing". I can't figure out how to do this. I used the designer to map a Thing entity to the multiple tables, but that makes it save the data to each table. I added separate DbSets, but they all use the Junk0Thing table. I can't find any attributes to fix this.

How should I approach this? Is there any way to accomplish this *and* still keep the designer? The other team members highly value the model update wizard and would be displeased if I broke that.

Is inheritance worth looking into? I wanted to avoid that because sometimes objects get moved from one table to the other (Junk0Thing to Junk1Thing), and I want to avoid having to maintain code that remembers to copy every field.

Comment: You need to create a table-per-type hierarchy. Make a `Thing` class that all `Junk{n}Thing`s inherit from. Then add a DbSet of `Thing`s to your context.

Comment: Well I don't want a single DbSet - I want to manually choose which table. And I also want to be able to easily do something like x = Junk0Things.First(); Junk0Things.Remove(x); Junk1Things.Add(x);

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to simply index the JunkLevel column in the existing table?

Comment: You can add a property with a getter that does `return this.Set<Junk0Thing>()` with type `DbSet<Thing>`.

Comment: Asad is right. We had exactly the same situation at my previous company and that's how we solved it.

Comment: I guess I should first ask whether you're allowed to add code to your DbContext. If you are, simply adding a property like `public DbSet<Thing> Junk0Things {get {return this.Set<Junk0Thing>();} }`. Otherwise, do the same thing, except as an extension method.

Comment: OK that works, thanks Asad and Craig. The only thing remaining is how do I move a row from Junk0Thing to Junk1Thing? Do I have to turn to a bunch of code or something like AutoMapper to copy property-by-property? @Dan we have indexes (and filtered indexes, and materialized views), but they're getting very large and making the optimizer take the right path or respond well is difficult.

Comment: Is it true that the EF designer still doesn't support table-per-concrete type? It errors, telling me to map the base Thing class. Can I write in this mapping by hand while leaving everything else designer friendly?

Comment: @MichaelGG TPT inheritance is fully supported by the designer if i recall correctly, TPC I'm not so sure about. As far as moving things between tables is concerned, I'm afraid some mapping code is unavoidable since `Junk0Thing` *is* a separate type from `Junk1Thing`. I usually use AutoMapper for this. The only other alternative I can think of is to change your entire table structure so you have a single table containing `ThingData`s, which represent all the information common to `Thing`s. A `Junk{n}Thing` then *has* a `ThingData` (as a property), instead of *being* a `ThingData` (contd)

Comment: ... and you can easily move them between different tables by creating a new eg. `Junk1Thing`, setting its `ThingData` property to the `ThingData` of the old `Junk0Thing`, and deleting the old `Junk0Thing`.

Comment: Thanks Asad for the detailed suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot map a single type to multiple tables.

However, you can inherit:

```
public abstract class JunkThing { }

public class Junk0Thing : JunkThing { }

public class Junk1Thing : JunkThing { }

public class Junk2Thing : JunkThing { }
```

This allows Entity Framework to make different models to different tables, while allowing you to work with the base type JunkTable for all your purposes.

To copy between types you would need to implement something like:

```
public abstract class JunkThing
{
     public TJunkThing CopyTo<TJunkThing>(TJunkThing destination) where TJunkThing : JunkThing
     {
          destination.Value1 = Value1;
          destination.Value2 = Value2;
     }

}
```

Comment: Does this work purely in the designer? I tried to set it up but I get an error that JunkThing needs to be mapped. If I do have to map it to EF by hand, can I mix that with the designer? My team does not want to discard the designer entirely.

Comment: It's easier with code-first POCO classes since you can just inherit the classes in code. Our team moved from the EDMX designer file to POCO classes and never looked back. However if you are committed to inheritance in model-first, then you should look into "Table Per Concrete Type" (TPC), which involves establishing inheritance on the EDMX designer and marking the base classes as "Abstract". More details here - http://huagati.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/mixing-inheritance-strategies-in-entity.html

Comment: As of at least EF6, you can map multiple tables to one type. Look at the Fluent Map() method.